# CrossRider's "appAPI.tabs" is undefined

Tags: crossrider

I have used the most basic demo:

appAPI.tabs.create('http://www.example.com');

And i saw on dev tools that "appAPI" doesn't have tabs at all.

I'm using chrome Version 33.0.1750.117 m
All other api functionality works fine.

Answer (score 0):

O.k. it was a stupid mistake, 
I needed to use this api in "background" scope.
Now it works fine.